# How to find $g(x)$ if $f(g(x))$ and$ f(x)$ are given?

Tags: functions

I'm attempting a question where $f(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ are given and the question is to find $g(x)$

How do I approach this problem?

What fundamentals should I keep in mind while encountering such questions?

Comment: Apply the inverse function $f^{-1}$, it it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y=f(x)$, try to write $x$ as a function of $y$.

For example, if $y=2x+3$, then $x=(y-3)/2$.  So $f^{-1}(x)=(x-3)/2$.

Apply this function to $f(g(x))$.  If $f(g(x))=x^2$, then $g(x)=f^{-1}(f(g(x))) = (x^2-3)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

You may try solving such questions using the chain rule of differentiation that is $dz/dx=dz/dy.dy/dx$
Suppose that we have to differentiate the following function - $$f(x)=sin(2x)$$
We define the inside and outside function to be- $$f(x)=sin(x)$$ and $$g(x)=2x$$
Then, the derivative of the composition will be as follows:
$$F'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$$$=cos2x*2$$$$F'(x)=2cos(2x)$$
Or else you can use this example to solve your question-
Given $F(x) = 3x - 1$ and $F(G(x)) = x² - 5x$, find $G(x)$.
$sol^n-$$$F(x)=3x-1$$
Then,$$ F(G(x))=3[G(x)]-1=x² - 5x $$ 
$$=>3[G(x)]=x² - 5x+1$$
$$=>G(x)=\frac13(x² - 5x+1)$$
I hope this example woulld help you.

Comment: I was able to solve by using the method given by @Michael
I'm trying to solve it by chain rule of differentiation as well, but I'm unable to, can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

For $g(x)$ when given $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ and $f(x)$:
$$g(x)=f^{-1}(f \circ g(x))$$

For $g(x)$ when given $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$ and $f(x)$:
$$g(x)=(f \circ g)(f^1(f \circ g)(x))$$

Thank me later even though I'm 2 years late..
 Your savior..

Comment: Lol about being 2 years late. This does only work when $f$ is invertible.

Comment: Unfortunately your  second formula doesn't work.